# Syntactic sugar for only assign if value is of type

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntactic-sugar

I am looking for the syntactic sugar version of this python code:

```py
if isinstance(external_function(x), str):
    y = external_function(x)
else:
    y = other_function(x)
```

I find that calling external_function twice is redundant. But I first need to check that external_function returns the right value type (i.e str) before assigning to y. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Umm... just `y = external_function(x)` then if it's not a string, `if not instance(y, str): y = other_function(x)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate `external_function(x)` first and assign it to `y`, and if `y` isn't a string, evaluate `other_function(x)` and assign it to `y`:

```
y = external_function(x)

if not isinstance(y, str):
    y = other_function(x)
```

You can also write the above as a ternary conditional:

```
y = external_function(x)
y = y if isinstance(y, str) else other_function(x)
```

Comment: but what if the call to `external_function` fails? Is there a way to default to other_function without a `try: except`

Comment: @AbdelJaidi No, there's not.

Answer (score 0):

You evaluate `external_function(x)` twice, you can prevent that like this:

```
y = external_function(x)

if not isinstance(y, str):
    y = other_function(x)
```

If you want syntactic sugar, you will have to write it yourself, I am not aware of anything built-in that is easier than this.

Here you go:

```
def function_chooser(fn_normal, fn_emergency, expected_type):
    def internal(x):
        try:
            result = fn_normal(x)
            if not isinstance(result, expected_type):
                return fn_emergency(x)
            return result
        except:
            return fn_emergency(x)
    return internal

x = 10

# auto_func is now a funcion that calls external_function and
# falls back to internal_function if it doesn't return a string
# or throws an error
auto_func = function_chooser(external_function, internal_function, str)

# It can be use just as any function, as it is one.
print(auto_func(x))
```